# CORS access to MongoDB via Apache Server on Windows7

Tags: javascript, ajax, windows, mongodb, apache

I am building a prototype application that does an Ajax GET call via javascript in an html page.   The configuration I am using is:

Windows/Apache Web Server (XAMPP)
MongoDB
Chrome Browser

All running on the same Windows7(32) machine.  The mongodb server and data are installed in  the C:\ path; the Apache server is in the C:\XAMPP path.  I can access the MongoDB server directly through the browser; for example a call to:

localhost:28017/ database/ collection

will return the collection's data in json format.

However, if I try running the same Ajax call in javascript via an html page, I get the error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http:// localhost:28017/ database/ collection.  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http:// localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

I modified/inspected my httpd.conf file and have the following set for :

```
<Directory />
   Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"    
   Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
   Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, Content-Type,
Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding"
   Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
AllowOverride none
Require all denied
</Directory>
```

I also confirmed that the headers_module is being loaded:

LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so

However, this does not work.   The port number is changing between the html and the ajax call  (80 vs. 28017), therefore a new domain.

Here is the script code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
console.log("xhr open")
xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:28017/ database/ collection/", false);
xhr.send();
```

Here are the response headers from the html call:

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Max-Age:1000
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:564
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Mon, 09 Jan 2017 23:47:06 GMT
ETag:"234-545b12ed82b40"
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Last-Modified:Mon, 09 Jan 2017 22:49:41 GMT
Server:Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/5.5.38
```

And all the headers from the xhr call:

```
General
Request URL:http://localhost:28017/ database/ collection/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK

Response Headers
Connection:close
Content-Length:369
Content-Type:text/plain;charset=utf-8
x-action:
x-ns:database.collection

Request Headers
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:28017
Origin:http:// localhost
Referer:http://localhost/ load_mongodb_data.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
```

Any assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**CORS** is a mechanism where restricted **R**esources can be requested from (**S**hared to) another domain - i.e. "**C**ross **O**rigin" ... *the domain owning the resource controls who can have it* - this is the important part of CORS, the owner of the resource permits or denies access to the resource

In your case, the page making the request is served on port 80, the resource is requested on port 28017

Think of port 80 as being **your** domain with **your** resources

Think of port 28017 being someone elses domain, and they have some resources you want to use

You can't "enable CORS" on **your** domain and expect the other domain to then grant you access to it's resources - if that's how CORS worked, there'd be no need for CORS to begin with

What you'll need to do is set those Access-Control-* headers on the server running on port 28017

Comment: I see - the MongoDB server has to provide the headers.  Thanks, that is very helpful.